# Randomly chose an element of one list that's NOT in a second list

Tags: python, list, random, unique

Say I have a `list2` of randomly chosen elements from a large `list1`. Is there a clever way of choosing an element from `list1` that's NOT already in `list2`?

For example:

```py
list1 = range(20,100)
list2 = [37,49,22,35,72] # could be much longer
    
while True:
    n = random.choice(list1)
    if n not in list2:
        break
    
# now n is an element of list1 that's not in list2
```

I feel like there must be a more efficient way of doing this than a guess-and-check while-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subtract `list2` of `list1`:

```
list3 = list(set(list1)-set(list2))
```

and choose from it randomly:

```
random.choice(list3)
```

**Note:** you need to reconvert the [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to a `list`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
import random

list1 = range(20,100)
list2 = [37,49,22,35,72]

not_in_list2 = [item for item in list1 if item not in list2]
n = random.choice(not_in_list2)
```

This uses a list comprehension to create a list of all elements in `list1` that aren't in`list2`. It then selects randomly from this list. Unlike when working with sets, this technique does not change the probability of items being selected, because it does not remove duplicate elements from `list1`.

Answer (score 1):

In case that there are no repeating elements in list1, this is a pythonic way, working with `set` and `-`:

```
import random

list1 = range(20,100)
list2 = [37,49,22,35,72] # could be much longer

n = random.choice(tuple(set(list1)-set(list2)))

# now n is an element of list1 that's not in list2
```

The `tuple` call is needed to avoid a `NotIndexable` exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to randomly select more than one item from a list, or select an item from a set, it's better to use `random.sample` instead of `choice`

```
import random
diff = set(list1)-set(list2)
num_to_select = 1 # set the number to select here.
list_of_random_items = random.sample(diff, num_to_select)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the overhead of creating a new list (or a new list and two sets) which can become quite costly if `list1` is very large, there is another option.

```
import random

list1 = range(20,100)
list2 = [37,49,22,35,72]

for i in list2:
    while i in list1:
        list1.remove(i)

random.choice(list1)
```

Just iterate through the items in `list2` and remove them from `list1`. Since [`list.remove()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) only removes the first occurrence of an item, I added a while-loop to ensure that all occurences are removed.